# Why can non-superuser delete files created by root?

Tags: linux

I created a file foo.txt as root.

But I can remove that user as o normal user. Authentications of the file is as below :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1          0 Oct 11 09:31 foo.txt
```

How is it possible? It is dangerous situation for real life examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deletion of a file requires write access to the *directory* that contains the file, not the file itself. You just have to keep in mind what an operation does. Deletion doesn't involve any changes to the file you're deleting, it just involves removing the pointer to it from the directory "file" that it's in.

Were you to open the file for write and attempt to change one of its bytes, you would see that it *is* protected from you. Note, this may be different to editing the file since that can be done by reading it, deleting the original, then writing a new copy (all of which can be done with read access to the file and write access to the directory).

And, no, it's not really dangerous since secure systems also protect the *directories* that contain real system files, such as `/etc`:

```
pax@paxBoxA> ls -ld /etc
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 11 14:45 /
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter what permissions are on that file. You need to have write permissions on the directory that contains the file.

(You can even remove files not owned by you if you have write permission for the directory. A confirmation question will appear and by answering with yes, the file will go away.)

Because you can remove the file, so if you can read that file, virtually you have "modified permission"

Say you have file named foo owned by root and its readable by you (everyone), under a dir what owned by you

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    4 May 11 12:34 foo
drwxr-xr-x 2 you     root 4.0K May 11 12:34 ./
```

Copy that file to a new file:

```
$ cp foo bar
```

-

```
rw-r--r-- 1 root    root       4 May 11 12:34 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 you     you        4 May 11 12:36 bar
drwxr-xr-x 2 you     root       4.0K May 11 12:36 ./
```

Edit the file "bar" to whatever you like

```
Move "bar" to "foo"

$ mv bar foo

-rw-r--r-- 1 you     you        4 May 11 12:36 foo
```

Now you have new file with same name, but of course different owner. But the point here is the content is changed

You doesnt have the modified permission, but you can rename/move/rm. I really dont get this kind of design!!

Comment: Basharat, it may help to think of files as just blobs of data on the disk somewhere. The file *names* and the permissions belong to the directory entries that reference those blobs (and there may be more than one of these references (hard links)). Even if you can't affect the blob through `/etc/important.cfg`, there may be another reference you can use to do it (i.e., one that's less protected). Bottom line, the UNIX model is very flexible (but, of course, possibly harder to comprehend if you *use* all that flexibility).